# Flutter - sdk set problem after set compile sdk 30 to 31

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-manifest

When I am using to set compile SDK 30 in flutter then I got these error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

 The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
 dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
 Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0.
 AAR metadata file: 
 C:\Users\WasiSoft\.gradle\caches\transforms3\6a6bfbcf60d09272b0cdf4bed2dc0443\
  transformed\appcompat-1.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

 The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
 dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
 Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.0.
 AAR metadata file: 
 C:\Users\WasiSoft\.gradle\caches\transforms3\8fe9ccdb464c8d3dff16cf232813d78c\
 transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.4.0\META-INF\com\
  android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

 The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
 dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
 Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.0.0.
 AAR metadata file: 
 C:\Users\WasiSoft\.gradle\caches\transforms3\aa5ebfefee6d35dee263bd0cd4753256\
 transformed\jetified -emoji2-views-helper-1.0.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\
 aarmetadata.properties.

 The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
 dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
 Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.0.0.
 AAR metadata file: C:\Users\WasiSoft\.gradle\caches\transforms- 
 3\b0e38b05362ae33360070f9b30618d9f\transformed\jetified-emoji21.0.0\METAINF\com\android\build 
  \gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

 The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
 dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
 Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.7.0.
 AAR metadata file: C:\Users\WasiSoft\.gradle\caches\transforms- 
 3\028820553fa44b6579541915f81b128d\transformed\core1.7.0\METAINF\com\android\build\gradle\aar
  -metadata.properties.

 The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
 dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
 Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0.
 AAR metadata file: C:\Users\WasiSoft\.gradle\caches\transforms- 
3\623708390cd51304eeeb10f79f7ceb8b\transformed\jetified-lifecycle-process-2.4.0\META- 
INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

 The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
 dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
 Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0.
 AAR metadata file: C:\Users\WasiSoft\.gradle\caches\transforms- 
 3\77475f45e2af1906c765abcaefbb8c4c\transformed\lifecycle-runtime-2.4.0\META- 
 INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

if I am using SDK 31 then I got this issue

```
 C:\Users\WasiSoft\AndroidStudioProjects\wsms_employee\android\app\src\
  main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
  android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 
  and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `andro
  id:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See 
  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.comple.example">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    tools:replace="android:label"
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:label="WSMS Employee"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"   
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|
   screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|
      layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:showWhenLocked="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:turnScreenOn="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
        <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
             Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
             screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
             gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
             Flutter's first frame. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
            android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />

</application>
   </manifest>
```

i tried all possible ways to get rid of this issue i dont know why this happens kindly anuone look into this.also how to set activity when compile sdk 31. which is very difficult in flutter

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: @StefanGaller everything but still failed.

Comment: @Adnanhaider any solution?

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan  kindly check my answer i hope you found this issue and solve it

Comment: @Ashkan kindly look answer

Comment: I just fixed the same issue ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/71146453/13698241

Answer (score 1):

@Abdullah Khan @Ashkan Yes i did that if you see my error there are dependencies in it so what i did first set compile sdk 30 then

goto Android-->build.gradle-->Open for Editing in Android Studio --> then a new screen open which look like it open in android studio natively and after go to all app/build.gradle and downgrade all dependencies which show error in it then after that sync project,invalidate cache and restart and then it works normally...